# persisting information through multiple recursive calls

Tags: java, recursion, overriding

I am extending a 3rd party class and overriding a method that I have made "recursive" like so:

```
public class SubFoo extends Foo {
    ....
    @Override
    public void bar(...) {
        recursiveSpecificSet.add(...);
        if(recursiveSpecificSet.contains(...)){ 
            ...
            methodCallThatCallsBar(...);
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Since this method is overrided, I have no control in the method signature.  I would like to pass information from the parent recursive call to its child through the recursiveSpecificSet, but I would like that information to be specific to that recursive chain.  For instance:

```
SubFoo sf = new SubFoo();
sf.methodCallThatCallsBar(...); // first call calls bar recursively 3 times
sf.methodCallThatCallsBar(...); // second call calls bar recursively 5 times
```

In the above code, the first call's recursiveSpecificSet variable should not interfere with the second call's recursiveSpecificSet.

Is this even possible?  I know you can usually pass info between recursive iterations through method parameters, but I do not have control on the method signature.  Multiple calls to the bar method can also occur in the same thread, so a thread local variable will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a threadlocal that stores recursion depth and the payload data. If upon entering `bar()` the threadlocal is null, initialize it with depth 1, otherwise increment depth. Upon leaving `bar()`, decrement depth and if it goes under `1`, delete the threadlocal. You'll probably have to do this in finally so it doesn't break in case of an exception being thrown.

```
public void bar() {
    if (threadLocal == null) {
        threadLocal.set(new Context(recursiveSpecificSet));
    }
    threadLocal.get().increaseDepth();

    try {
        ...
        methodCallThatCallsBar(...);
        ...
    }
    finally {
        threadLocal.get().decreaseDepth();
        if (threadLocal.get().isExitRecursion()) {
            threadLocal.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: a thread local variable will only work if each call to bar() is self contained in a thread, right? This is not the case.

Comment: You mean you have a recursive call where the recursion spans over several threads? Like you instantiate a new thread somewhere within the recursion loop and continue the recursion in that new thread? If so, we need to know all the constraints then, you're adding more and more of them to the problem. What exactly do you still consider one recursive invocation and what is considered to be a separate invocation?

Comment: No, I mean I could only have one thread.  If I only have one thread, my ThreadLocal variable will always be the same for every recursive call.

Comment: I want each recursive chain to have its own variable

Comment: It won't because you count the recursion depth and when you exit the outer-most invocation, you delete the threadlocal's content. When you subsequently call `bar()` again, you initialize the threadlocal again with another value.

Comment: oh, I understand what you are saying now.  That could work!  I will try that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, the answer is not to make `bar` recursive, but to make `bar` call a private helper method that is recursive.

```
@Override
public void bar() {
    helper(new HashSet<>());
}

private void helper(Set<String> recursiveSpecificSet) {
    ...
    helper(recursiveSpecificSet);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!  This would of worked for the way I worded the question, but I had removed some complexity for sake of simplicity.  I have updated the question.  Essentially, I do not call the bar() method directly.  It is actually called by another 3rd party method.  So I cannot create a helper method because it is not direct recursion.